# PHP capture value of second row of div id

Tags: php, html-parsing

When I want to capture the value by ID using curl php
The first row is captured I need to capture the second row only

here is my example :

```
<div wire:id="y77K2o0hTQAFEdNLTrGR" 
<div wire:id="Em80tXfef2e95jbAWdLS"
```

How can I capture the second value ( <div wire:id="Em80tXfef2e95jbAWdLS" )

i use this

```
$id = trim(strip_tags(getStr($page,'<div wire:id="','"')));
```

Comment: How are you capturing the first row? Is this a snippet or your have invalid markup?

Comment: Show the curl code.

Comment: $id = trim(strip_tags(getStr($page,'<div wire:id="','"')));

As you can see, only the first row is captured, but I just need the second row

(<div wire:id="Em80tXfef2e95jbAWdLS" )

Comment: I am fetching this information from a website page using curl

The id of the div is same but the value is  diffirent, And I need the value that is inside the div id But I am unable to capture second value

Comment: @LimaAds What's inside `getStr`?

Comment: @nice_dev
page response Which is $page

here is $page response : 


<div wire:id="y77K2o0hTQAFEdNLTrGR" < /div>
<div wire:id="Em80tXfef2e95jbAWdLS" </div >


I've also set it inside getStr (<div wire:id=",")

echo $page;

I only get the first div result
But I want the second result

Comment: @LimaAds You will need to use DOMDocument class for a proper selection.

Comment: @LimaAds See this https://onlinephp.io/c/2c9c9

Comment: Thanks very much, but how can this be combined with curl

example : https://onlinephp.io/c/594e6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your example at: https://onlinephp.io/c/594e6

I have a few suggestions as follows:

1, CURLOPT_HEADER should have a value of 0.

2, After "Create" the document, you should load HTML from a string.

```
<?php


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: www.example.com';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

$d = new DOMDocument();

$d->loadHTML($page);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($d->getElementsByTagName('div')); $i++) {
    var_dump($d->getElementsByTagName('div')[$i]->getAttribute('id'));
}
```